# fire a classLiss.add event only once in a loop in raw JS

Tags: javascript, loops, addeventlistener

everybody.
I've a problem probably well-know, but I can't find a solution also looking for it in the WEB.
I'm working on a progressive bar that shows the parts included in a 'title section' during screen scrolling.
Everything works fine except when I try to add a class (and remove it), because I'm not able to fire the event only once in the *for-next* loop.
Here is a part of the HTLM:

```
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <section class="onTop">
        <nav>
            <div class="scroll-title">MENU</div>
          <div id="scroll-total">
            <div id="scroll-part"></div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </section>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="title">FIRST TITLE</div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum, aut quo blanditiis hic numquam, sapiente maiores id,
[etc.]
```

here is the CSS parts those apply:

```
.scroll-title{
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 15.5vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 14%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) rotate(90deg);
  border: 1px solid red;
  transition: font-size .25s ease-out;
}
.scroll-title.action{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

The JS code put titles' heigths refecences in an array, then check if the scroll position is inside a part an move the bar. In that time the code changes the single title's DIV containing "scroll-title" class.
My idea is to add a CSS class to animate (with a *transition*) the title. So, I'm using a *addEventListener* to add and remove the class, but I'd like to fire this event only once, and I can't find a way to do it.
Thisi a part of the code:

```
let titleScroll = document.querySelector('.scroll-title');
let band = document.getElementById('scroll-total');
let scroll = document.getElementById('scroll-part');
let pageTitlesRif =[], pageTitlesText =[];
let pageTitles = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .title');
pageTitlesRif  = [0];
pageTitlesText =['MENU'];
let rect;
let tot = band.offsetWidth;
      let totSide = bandSide.offsetHeight;
      for (var i = 0; i < pageTitles.length; i++) {
        rect = pageTitles[i].getBoundingClientRect();
        pageTitlesText.push(pageTitles[i].innerText);
        pageTitlesRif.push(rect.bottom + document.documentElement.scrollTop);
      }
      let scrollHeight = Math.max(
        document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
        document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
      );
      pageTitlesRif.push(scrollHeight);
      console.log(scrollHeight);

      window.onscroll = function() {
        for (var i = 1; i < pageTitlesRif.length; i++) {
          if (window.pageYOffset > pageTitlesRif[i - 1] && window.pageYOffset < pageTitlesRif[i]) {
            titleScroll.classList.add('action');
            let transitionEnd = whichTransitionEvent();
            titleScroll.addEventListener(transitionEnd, putClass, false);
            titleScroll.innerText = pageTitlesText[i - 1];
            scroll.style.left = (pageTitlesRif[i-1] * tot / scrollHeight).toString()+ 'px';
            scroll.style.width = ((pageTitlesRif[i] - pageTitlesRif[i - 1])  * tot / 
            scrollHeight).toString() + 'px';
          }
        }
      }

      let putClass = function(){
        this.classList.remove('action');
      }

      function whichTransitionEvent(){
          var t;
          var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
          var transitions = {
            'transition':'transitionend',
            'OTransition':'oTransitionEnd',
            'MozTransition':'transitionend',
            'WebkitTransition':'webkitTransitionEnd'
          }

          for(t in transitions){
              if( el.style[t] !== undefined ){
                  return transitions[t];
              }
          }
      }
```

Has somebody a suggestion to fix this?

Comment: Didnt read the whole code, its not so effective to paste the whole page of the code and expect people to read it. But from the description you should just check if the element already has class and if no then add class. So even if the code is called many times it will add class only when its needed. Besides that, addClass method just adds the class to element and if the element already has the class then it doesn't do anything

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well, my point is that: after the event firing that add the class, I need to remove the class itself, waiting for the following change that apply when the next title is reached with page scrolling. So, if I act it inside a loop, the adding and removing are continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had the solution under my eyes, and I made a mountain out of a molehill...
It's enuogh to control if the existing title is different from the one that comes in the loop, like this:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
        for (var i = 1; i < pageTitlesRif.length; i++) {
          if (window.pageYOffset > pageTitlesRif[i - 1] && window.pageYOffset < pageTitlesRif[i]) {
           if (titleScroll.innerText != pageTitlesText[i - 1]){
              titleScroll.innerText = pageTitlesText[i - 1];
              titleScroll.classList.add('action');
              let transitionEnd = whichTransitionEvent();
              titleScroll.addEventListener(transitionEnd, putClass, false);
              scroll.style.left = (pageTitlesRif[i-1] * tot / scrollHeight).toString()+ 'px';
              scroll.style.width = ((pageTitlesRif[i] - pageTitlesRif[i - 1])  * tot / 
              scrollHeight).toString() + 'px';
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

In this way, the code on the title (and on the other tag elements) in executed once.